# How to Sync Azure with Github, issues: Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\s\ because it does not exist; Repository not found fetch failed; Filename too long

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

OK, so the main question here is: How to Sync Github with Azure?

Now, I had main reference source: How to synchronize Azure Repos with External Git Repos
https://faun.pub/how-to-synchronize-azure-repos-with-external-git-repos-70ff92e51c63
And that is perfect match, but here is a catch, it is kind of abstract and you have to have work with Azure experience, like knowing what is YAML for and how to use it.

Long story short, it did not work. And then I found this gentleman's video: Merge From Github to Azure DevOps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kks1pCG51bI

That is super close, yet there still were several error and bugs ,like:

1. Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\s\copyrepo~' because it does not exist;
2. remote: Not Found fatal: repository 'https://github.com/***/' not found ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 5.443 seconds before retry.
3. error: unable to create file Filename too long

So, that is a bummer...
I mean, yes, you technically can create and synchronize GitHub repo with Azure, but you have to create new GitHub repo, with existing one there was: error: unable to create file Filename too long.

Please tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following yaml file as I used to sync Github to Azure Repos:

```
name: Sync Azure with Github

variables:

  REMOTE_ADDR: 'https://github.com/{user{/{repo.git}'

stages:

  - stage: syncing Repos

    displayName: syncing Repos

    jobs:

      - job: run_Git_Commands

        displayName: run_Git_Commands

        continueOnError: false

        steps:

        - checkout: self

          clean: true

          persistCredentials: true

          displayName: run_commands

        - bash: | 

            git checkout master

            git remote add repoGithub $(REMOTE_ADDR)

            git fetch repoGithub master

            git reset --hard repoGithub/master

            git pull --rebase repoGithub master

            git push --force origin
```

Comment: Thank you jinkc-MSFT for you r input, I do appreciate it!)